# SSL Incompatabilities between Java7 and Java8?

Tags: java, ssl

We have a server-side process running on java 7:
**java -version:**
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

It accepts SSL connections from our home-grown java application (launched via a properly signed JNLP).

Normally, this works like a dream, regardless of whether the client application runs in a Java 6 or Java 7 JVM.

However, when launching the same client-app using Java 8 (from a MAC), we encounter a SSL issue where the server breaks off the connection (we checked with wireshark to confirm) with the following exception:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1605)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1573)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:971)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:876)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:750)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)

...

Based on this, the error is specifically vague...
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39844/getting-ssl-alert-write-fatal-bad-record-mac-during-openssl-handshake

JVM Version on MAC:
Java 8 Update 45

Things I've tried:

- Adding this to the JNLP (from
  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8030806):
- Limiting which ciphers are allowed/not allowed on the server:

`SSLEngine engine = getSslContext().createSSLEngine();
String[] avail = engine.getSupportedCipherSuites();
Set availableCiphers = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(avail));
availableCiphers.retainAll(GOOD_CIPHERS);
 engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(this.availableCiphers.toArray(new String[this.availableCiphers.size()]));`

- Surprisingly, when running the server process locally, using
  jdk1.6.0_20, this error does NOT happen and everything works fine.

Let me know what additional information will help to find the cause/resolution of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the server's JDK to the latest java7 version seems to have fixed the issue.